# Ignore some dependencies when installing from bower.json

Tags: javascript, json, bower

I have a dependency which I want to ignore temporarily from being installed but I still want to keep it in the `bower.json` file because don't want to try to remember its name if I will need it again.

How can I make it possible to not install some dependencies, something like putting special flag for them in `bower.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure there isn't a way to do this nicely with bower.json.

you *could* do something like

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "rm -rf /bower_components/dependency"
}
```